# Node.js Issues with TwitterBot

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, bots

I created a twitter bot via the instructions here:
https://medium.freecodecamp.com/easily-set-up-your-own-twitter-bot-4aeed5e61f7f#.5ifmh6ihn

I keep getting an error "Cannot read property 'id_str' of undefined Query String". I don't know much about node.js and just want this thing to work. I googled the error and didn't find much help. I left a comment on the post and haven't received any response there. Any help?

Comment: Your error (and stacktrace) must be mentioning a line number in your file, where you are trying to access `<object>.id_str`. `object` is undefined there. Make sure object is initialized before you access its attributes.

Comment: Post your code.